# Android table header views

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an iPhone application which has a `UITableView` and a header for it. It was fairly trivial to do and had no issues. Is there something similar with `ListView` in Android? I tried searching for it and found no real solution. Is there any example (on github or any place) that has a work around?

Basically I want a header view, with two grouped tables below it. I figured out already how to do the grouped in Android, but still struggling with headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. I have a `View` defined in another xml file, and I get it like so:

```
View header = View.inflate(act, R.layout.table_header, null);
```

I then make it a header like below:

```
list.addHeaderView(header);
```